# Convert user from mstsc /admin to just mstsc for RDP

Tags: remote-desktop

I have a user accessing a server and they have to RDP using `mstsc /admin`.

How do I remove `/admin` from my user, and just use the RDP with `mstsc`, but not `mstsc /admin`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> **Convert user from mstsc /admin to just mstsc for RDP**
>
> How to remove admin from my user, and just take the RDP by just using
>   mstsc, but not mstsc /admin.

Right-click on the shortcut icon they click on to RDP into the server with the `/admin` switch, select `Properties`, and go to the `shortcut` tab. In the `target` field simply remove the `/admin` characters and press `OK`.

Once the change is made to that shortcut, when it's used without it, it'll not RDP into the console session of that machine any longer.

### Before Removal

[image]

### After Removal

[image]

---

### Update

<sub>[Source](http://support.jumpdesktop.com/entries/197765-logon-your-interactive-logon-privilege-has-been-disabled)</sub>

> **Logon: "Your interactive logon privilege has been disabled"**
>
> Follow these steps if you see a dialog box with the message Your
>   interactive logon privilege has been disabled when trying to logon to
>   your PC.
>
> This message usually means your domain user account has the Terminal
>   Services logon privilege disabled in Active Directory. Please contact
>   your system administrator to re-enable this privilege for your domain
>   account.
>
> For Administrators: The Deny this user permissions to log on to any
>   Terminal Server setting for the user should be unchecked as seen in
>   the Windows Server 2003 screen shot below:

[image]

- [**Microsoft KB 265382**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/265382)
- [**Microsoft KB 265382**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/815266)

---

[**Deny RDP Permission with Group Policy**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2258492)

> **RESOLUTION**
>
> To deny a user or a group logon via RDP, explicitly set the "Deny
>   logon through Remote Desktop Services" privilege. To do this access a
>   group policy editor (either local to the server or from a OU) and set
>   this privilege:
>
> 1. Start | Run | Gpedit.msc if editing the local policy or chose the appropriate policy and edit it.
> 2. Computer Configuration | Windows Settings | Security Settings | Local Policies | User Rights Assignment.
> 3. Find and double click "Deny logon through Remote Desktop Services"
> 4. Add the user and / or the group that you would like to dny access.
> 5. Click ok.
> 6. Either run gpupdate /force /target:computer or wait for the next policy refresh for this setting to take effect.

---

### Update2

[**TechNet**](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/8987ad6d-5d19-44a9-8835-16208127fdd5/increase-rdp-connections-to-windows-2008-r2)

> Terminal Service access by default allows only two connections for
>   remote administration. It was designed solely for remote
>   administration and not for users to access.
>
> If you need more than two users, such as to allow your users to
>   connect remotely wtih their own desktop, do work, etc, then you must
>   upgrade to what used to be called Terminal Server Application Mode or
>   now called, Remote Desktop Services. However, this requires purchasing
>   CALs (client access licenses) and , then once purchased, then you
>   would:
>
> 1. Install the Remote Desktop Services Role.
> 2. Install the TS Licensing role service.
> 3. Open TS Licensing Manager and connect to the Terminal Services license server.
> 4. Activate the license server.
> 5. Install required TS CALs on the license server.
> 6. You then have to reinstall your apps in "Install Mode" so they will be available for your users.

- [**Terminal Services Licensing**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770371(WS.10).aspx)
- [**Remote Desktop Licensing**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732684.aspx)

Comment: I guess, have asked the question in a wrong way, problem am facing is, I have a server, where all the users can take remote desktop to that server by just using mstsc. but I can only take the remote desktop by using ‘mstsc /admin’ if I use just mstsc to take RDP am getting am error which says  -  "Your interactive login privilege has been disabled. Please contact your administrator”. challenge am facing here is only TWO users can take RDP using “mstsc /admin” at the same time. Kindly help me in resolving this issue. I have checked the above setting. Target says "C:\Windows\System32\mstsc.exe"

Comment: RDP is for connecting Win 2008 R2. It has got permissions for 10 users to RDP. three users can only take RDP by typing  "mstsc /admin" in RUN and others by typing "mstsc" in RUN. all the users will use RDP at the same time. Issue here is only two users can login by typing 'mstsc /admin' in run at the same time. but there are there users who can only login by using '/admin' and these users cannot RDP by just mstsc.
I now want these three users to RDP by just using “mstsc” so that all the users can login at the same time.

Comment: @hari I updated my answer with an UPDATE 2 section which has some resources but it sounds like your RD licensing or terminal services CALs aren't configured correctly for the 10 you have. The **Remote Desktop Licensing** link should take you to the main page with other pages going over everything you need in detail.

Comment: An answer consisting of screenshots of text is rather useless, please transcribe them as quotes.

Comment: @hari Please take a moment and look over [**Accepting An Answer**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) to ensure you understand how this question and answer site works to close the loop on your questions that get an answer that works to resolve your issues. It's as simple and checking the little check mark beside the answer that works to resolve your inquiry.